# Changing to new $q syntax in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, q, eslint

I have the following code

```
function onpagechange(page, limit)
{
    var  deferred = $q.defer();
    loadUsers(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

which gives me following error via eslint: `You should not create a new promise with this syntax. Use the $q(function(resolve, reject)`

What is the best way to migrate to the new $q syntax. I think I will be better at dealing with this problem if I was 100% sure what the function is returning.

Comment: Why do you pass `deferred` to `loadUsers`? `loadUsers` should create the promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [`$q` constructor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor) returns a promise which can be resolved in the function you pass to it.

---

Update:

```
function onpagechange(page, limit)
{
    return $q(loadUsers)
}

function loadUsers(resolve, reject) {
    return $http().then(resolve, reject);
}
```

Comment: so on defered param of loadUsers, I can perform resolve and reject methods?

Comment: Bedankt Martijn :) got it!

Answer (score -1):

in your loadUsers function you have to:

1. resolve the derived promise with the value by calling :`defer.resolve(result);`

or

2. reject the derived promise with the reason : `defer.reject(reason);`

for example :

```
function onpagechange(page, limit)
   {
    var  deferred = $q.defer();
    loadUsers(deferred);
    return deferred.promise;
    }

   function loadUsers(defer)
    {
      $http.get('users.json').success(function(result) {
        defer.resolve(result);
       }).error(function(err){
        defer.reject(err);
       });    
     }
```